# Как подгружать информацию на свой сайт с сайта IKEA по артикулу товара?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Это нужно для сайта по доставке товара из этого магазина.
Например, как тут — [dostavkin.su](http://dostavkin.su/) или тут — [tomsk-ikea.ru](http://tomsk-ikea.ru/)
сам сайт [IKEA](http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/allproducts/)

Т.е. человек на сайте ikea копирует артикул понравившегося товара и вставляет его на сайте по доставке и после нажатия кнопочки подгружается вся необходимая информация о товаре.

Comment: Пишите свой парсер сайта ikea. Или пользуйтесь сторонними https://www.google.com/search?q=ikea+api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Александр, давайте разобьем вашу вопрос на части, что бы не закрывать? Вам понадобится API (в этом вопросе), а вопросы по реализации приложения для загрузки можете задать в отдельном вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайт IKEA имеет API, закрытое, необходимое для виджетов и мобильного приложения, но подходящее под вашу задачу:

Запрос на получение товара:

```
http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/%productId%/?type=xml&dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes
```

Запрос на проверку наличия:

```
http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/iows/catalog/availability/%productId%
```

Пример:

```
http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/00285183/?type=xml&dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes
```

Comment: есть ли у Вас описание API IKEA?